# Phonegap app stop working when someone change system time while application is working

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova

Any idea why changing system time to past while application is working can block it?

I started the application, then I switched it to work in the background. I changed the system time by subtracting a few hours. After returning to the application it was locked, events, scroll, etc. Did not work. I debugged application, but I didn't see any reason for this kind of behavior. The same thing happens on Android and iOS. I'm using phonegap 2.9.1.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the system time while a previously started app is in the background, the change does not reflect in the app. I've noticed this behaviour on the Android browser at least. This means that for example JavaScript functions keep returning old time in places.

This can cause the app to hang if you are using JavaScript functions like `setTimeout()` to run app behaviour. I also noticed that CSS animations that use timing don't execute correctly after a system time change.

One crude solution is to refresh the whole phonegap app each time it resumes by calling       `window.location.reload()` on the phonegap resume event.